# creating aliases with for loop (bash_profile)

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a for loop in my .bash_profile to loop through all directories in my github folder and create an alias to open then in a project workspace.

I have a working script below, however each of the aliases gets bound to the last result.

e.g. if the directory contains:
dir1
dir2
dir3

the final aliases look like this:

```
op_dir1='cd ~/Documents/GitHub/dir3 && open . && atom .' 
op_dir2='cd ~/Documents/GitHub/dir3 && open . && atom .'
op_dir3='cd ~/Documents/GitHub/dir3 && open . && atom .'
```

Here is the initial code:

```
# Git Directories Init
for d in ~/Documents/GitHub/*
do
    echo ${d##*/} && alias op_${d##*/}='cd $d && open . && atom .'
done
```

Comment: Why not just create a function to open the dir passed as an arg? Something like `opdir() { cd ~/Documents/GitHub/"$1" && open . && atom .; }` which you call as `opdir dir1`, etc. when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are single-quoting `$d` and delaying its expansion until the alias is run. You want it to be expanded right now, when you're defining the alias.

In bash, `alias` is a shell builtin that takes a single argument of the form `key=value`. The single argument of `alias` is split at the first `=` sign, so this script will still work if your directories contain the `=` character.

However, it will break if one of your directories has a `'` character in it.

```
for d in ~/Documents/Github/*
do
    dir="${d##*/}"
    alias "op_${dir}=cd '$d' && open . && atom ."
done
```

since `cd`ing your shell to the new directory, opening the directory in Finder, and opening it in Atom are all independent things, I'd recommend doing something like the following

```
for d in ~/Documents/Github/*
do
    dir="${d##*/}"
    alias "op_${dir}=cd '$d' && open '$d' && atom '$d'"
done
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! This is exactly what I needed and with some extra background info.

Comment: @Guy, I messed it up a couple of times, but now it should be good.